# Cannot add keyboard shortcuts in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard

As of an unknown moment, I cannot add custom keyboard shortcuts anymore. Isn't there supposed to be an add button somewhere here? [image: no add button]

Answer (score 2):

On the screenshot the panel with more choices is completely withdrawn (on the left). Once you pull it out, it makes it possible to select "Application Shortcuts" and then a "+" button appears which provides the sought functionality.

Bottom line: don't lose your panels!

Answer (score 0):

The *add* button appears if you select the *Applications* item from the list on the left.

For the rest of the given items, you can't add new shortcuts this way, but change the default ones. To do so, you must, first **check** the shortcut, enabling it, then you'll be able to **double-click** the shortcut and, holding down the new keys, change it to a new one.

Comment: But by adding I don't mean editing an existing one. The screen shot actually shows the actual complete list of shortcuts I happen to have at the moment… isn't it too short? What about adding a custom one for an arbitrary application? I remember this was possible before.

Comment: @nomadcoder The *add* button appears if you select *Applications* .

Comment: Ok, I got it. As you see on the screenshot, I have the left list hidden - and totally forgot about it. Stupid me. Thanks!

Comment: I'll update my answer, pointing out the difference between the selected items on the list.

Comment: The key moment here was to unhide the left panel (see screenshot).